# Как заставить появляться абсолютный блок при наведении на circle в svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Как заставить блок появляться на одной высоте и с левой стороны? Проблема в том что circle в svg спозиционированны через cx и transform. И значения через .position() и .offset() делает расчет от начала страницы.
пример торговой площадки со стима но у них canvas.При наведении на график появляется блок с абсолютным позиционированием сверху в любой точке графика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот мой [график](http://serjo96.github.io/zakaz-biletov/) но уже svg

Comment: вопрос не очень понятен, если только `заставить блок появляться на одной высоте и с левой стороны`, то поменяй стили у класса `.hover_block { top:0; left:0;...}`

Comment: @ravend все не так просто. Блок должен появится рядом с кружками в svg лучше с левой стороны. Но блок находится не в svg и тут нужен скрипт. Итог должен быть как на скрине

Comment: @ravend собственно это видно уже на проекте, но из за адаптивы нужен скрипт для того что бы автоматически вычислять положение блока

Comment: внедрите `div` в `svg` через `foreignObject`, или вычисляйте координаты выбранного `circle` через `svg.createSVGMatrix()...`